# Python - replace commas in string

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have the following *string*:

string = "[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],,,,[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[14001],[14001],[14001]"

For putting the string into a list later, I want to remove 3 of the 4 commas in the middle of the string. I don't want a solution like ***string.replace(",,,,",",")*** because in other cases there are 7 or more commas in a row and then this doesn't work. Do you have a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to search for two or more comma's and replace them with one comma.

```
result = re.sub(",,+", ",", string, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
```

> ,,+
>
> Options: Case insensitive; Free-spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Regex syntax only
>
> Match the character “,” literally «,»
>
> Match the character “,” literally «,+»
>
> Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way, Use `split` and `join`

```
>>> ','.join([i for i in string.split(',') if i])
'[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[11801 14001],[14001],[14001],[14001]'
```